# Tikz: Dimension too large -- is there a workaround?

Tags: tikz-pgf, dimensions

I've created a complex drawing in Tikz (~1MB of text in total).
This drawing is too large.
LuaLaTeX aborts with the error "Dimension too large".

Normally, the advice is to simply scale down all coordinates and lengths until it fits.
However, this is rather inconvenient, as this drawing contains a large number of these.
Also, it contains text that I would need to scale in the same fashion.

Is there any way to work around the limitations of LaTeX dimensions with minimal changes to the tikz drawing?
Would it perhaps help to scale all nodes and distances only (e.g. via `\node[scale=0.01]`), so the inner content of nodes does not need to be adjusted?

Comment: "Dimension too large" has nothing to do with the code size(memory/disk size). -so you should be able to create a Minimal Working Example. How did you end up in a situation, where is it needed to scale someting by a factor of `0.01` ? Was the TikZ picture intended for a poster? -but not any longer?

Comment: The image contains a large graph with many thousands of nodes. Each node contains a tabular with some further stuff in it - that's where the text size comes from, and why I'm reluctant to post it as well as to edit the file. The rendered graph itself is also huge, it needs to be scaled down by more something like 0.01 to fit on a page. I'm not surprised about the dimension error - I just hope to fix it without editing a lot.

Comment: You most certainly do not want to post that here. That is why you need to make a MWE with the same error. You still do not explain how you ended up in a situation like this. What was the intended usage of a picture so large, and has that purpose now changed?

Comment: it is not necessarly the total dimension. E.g. you get a dimension too large error from `\pgfmathsetmacro\test{400*100/100}` , while `\pgfmathsetmacro\test{400/100*100}` works fine. You could try if `\usetikzlibrary {fpu} \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}` helps.

Comment: The image is generated by a program. Its dimensions are truly too large (>+16k points). I've since abandoned the project because the simple idea I proposed did not seem to work.